# How should we promote Martial Arts SE?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We're well into our public beta now, but our traffic is remaining slow and our QPD (Questions per Day) is very low. What can we do to a.) draw more traffic, and b.) encourage them to ask questions?

Some ideas may be:

- Reference/Link back to questions here in response to questions on other forums.
- Add links to the site and its questions on our own sites.
- Keyword loading old questions (applicably).

What are some ways that we can boost the traffic and market MA.SE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A big one is just referencing and linking back to here.  Don't spam of course, but when you are engaged in a community and a question comes up that we have an answer for, link to it and if the cultural rules allow then stick a link in your signature.

Something else: If your instructors, fellow students, etc might have an interest then send them here.  Let's see if we can recruit some good subject matter experts in a wide array of martial arts.

Other than that, there are probably some [specific things](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/) we can think of over time as the site grows.

Comment: SEO - It also helps if MA.SE starts to show up in searches for common questions.  It's still early so there is opportunity for more questions to be asked.

Comment: SEO is about making things show up in search engines. What I am talking about is a side effect of trying to recruit more great people in a more targeted fashion.

Answer (score 1):

I think the SE devs have already got a good handle on SEO, so keyword loading shouldn't be necessary. Although it is disappointingly slow at the moment I would expect traffic to accelerate in the future both as Google rank starts happening and as various content rippers start echoing the content around.

Can the guys at SE provide any projections on numbers using comparatively sized betas that have already occurred? There have been enough betas now that they should have collected enough numbers to be able to plot whether this beta is in the red zone or not.

Comment: Take a look at the [site's stats on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4470/martial-arts). Way too few questions and visits. We are definitely in the red zone!